# What is wrong with this SQL Code?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am writing this code and it keeps giving me the error: missing right parenthesis. Am I not finding it or something? I have other code that looks like this and worked, but for some reason, this is not wanting to go through. It says it is happening around line 2 of my code....

SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIES
(title_id NUMBER (10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
title VARCHAR2 (60) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR2 (400) NOT NULL,
rating VARCHAR2 (4) CHECK (rating= 'G','PG','PG13','R'),
category VARCHAR2 (20) CHECK (category= 'DRAMA','COMEDY','ACTION','CHILD','SCIFI','DOCUMENTARY'),
release_date NOT NULL),
PRIMARY KEY (title_id));
```

Comment: This is not MySQL syntax. Trying to convert from another DB engine?

Comment: Not sure what you are telling me. I am new to all of this. I put this code into ORACLE database to create the table and it's not wanting to create because of a right parenthesis apparently missing.

Comment: I see. I replaced the MySQL DB tag with Oracle in your question

Comment: this is typo? right?

Comment: Release_date doesn't have field type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There  are couple of mistakes in your code.

- unwanted parenthesis after `release_date` column and a missing datatype
- For checking list of values you have used `=` but you need to use
  `IN`

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIES
  (
     title_id     NUMBER (10) NOT NULL, -- unique key will be overridden by the Primary key 
     title        VARCHAR2 (60) NOT NULL,
     description  VARCHAR2 (400) NOT NULL,
     rating       VARCHAR2 (4) CHECK (rating IN ( 'G', 'PG', 'PG13', 'R')), -- Should be IN instead of = 
     category     VARCHAR2 (20) CHECK (category IN ( 'DRAMA', 'COMEDY', 'ACTION', 'CHILD', 'SCIFI', 'DOCUMENTARY')), -- Should be IN instead of = 
     release_date timestamp NOT NULL, -- Unwanted close parenthesis and missing datatype
     PRIMARY KEY (title_id)
  );
```

Comment: release_date has no type

Comment: @igr - yeah missed it

Comment: Maybe date or timestamp, datetime is not an Oracle column type

Comment: Thanks both of you! Sorry I am new to all of this and surprised I didn't have more mistakes than I did! Thanks again.  :)

Comment: UNIQUE on title_id is superfluos, as it is covered by primary key

Comment: @igr - In fixing the error I missed to check the logical things